# Why does terminal repeat "//: is a directory" after I source .bash_profile?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal, shell

```
Sergios-MBP:~ home$ nano ~/.bash_profile
Sergios-MBP:~ home$ source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: //: is a directory
-bash: //: is a directory
-bash: //: is a directory
-bash: //: is a directory
-bash: //: is a directory
-bash: //: is a directory
-bash: //: is a directory
Sergios-MBP:~ home$
```

My question is why does "-bash:" appear, is that normal and
more importantly, why is this message of //: is a directory show up
a few times or even at all, if I'm just source(ing) my newly edited 
.bash_profile?

Very new here, any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

-Sergio

Comment: I bet you're using `//` as comments. bash comments begin with `#`

Comment: Oh @glennjackman that makes perfect sense. Thank you so much. This is the first question I've ever posted and wow, that was a fast answer. Better than the hours of searching I usually do for a simple case. Got it!

Comment: Feel free to post an answer to your question, so future readers get the Q and the A

Comment: Oh ok. I see, your comment/answer is just that, a comment and not technically an "answer". Thanks for the lesson, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from @glennjackman comment. I tried it out and it worked.

The `-bash` is just from my experience a separation of context in that it is the bash terminal session's voice and response to my command.

The `//: is not a directory` part that repeated itself was equivalent to the amount of commented out lines I had in my .bash_profile utilizing the wrong syntax `//`. I should have been using a `#` sign for commenting out lines. Once I corrected this, I did not get any more error reporting back to me when I `source` the file.